# No puedo guardar el resultado de un cURL en una variable de PHP

Tags: php, post, curl

Cuando se ejecuta el curl_exec en vez de guardar el resultado en la variable $respuesta se imprime el resultado de forma automática (sin usar una función para imprimir), pero mi mayor problema es que no puedo guardar ese resultado en una variable. Cuando imprimo $respuesta en vez de salir la respuesta del servidor, me sale es 1. Les agradezco su ayuda.

```
<?php

$servidor = 'servidorx';
$fields = array( 'key' => '12345',
  'action' => 'balance');
$fields_string = http_build_query( $fields );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $servidor );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
$respuesta = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo 'Resultado: ';
print_r($respuesta);

?>
```

[image: Respuesta del código]

Me reservo el nombre del servidor y apikey por cuestiones de seguridad.

Comment: te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: lo que has mostrado no representa ningun error: `Resultado:  1`  es lo que a devuelto el api ...

Comment: sin mas contexto e informacion no podremos ayudarte. ya que no hay un error visible o de codigo .

Answer (score 2):

Es debido a la opción `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` puesta a `false`.

Si le pasas `true`, en vez de imprimir la response te la retorna en `curl_exec($ch)`

El `1` que ves en tu code es pq la transfer fue exitosa. Usando `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` => `true` el resultado de `curl_exec` será o la response o `false`.

```php
$servidor = 'servidorx';
$fields = array(
  'key' => '12345',
  'action' => 'balance'
);
$fields_string = http_build_query( $fields );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $servidor );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$respuesta = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

if ( false !== $respuesta) {
  echo 'Exito!'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo 'Falla!'.PHP_EOL;
}

echo 'Resultado: ';
print_r($respuesta)
```